# Название затвора на двери подлодки

Tags: терминология

Речь о круглой детали, вращением которой запирают дверь.

Comment: Похоже? См. http://germes.land/products/ball_valves/handwheels/

Comment: @slava1947 Да. Спасибо за ссылку. Она помогла найти новую информацию. По ГОСТу, эта штука не может называться штурвалом. Цитирую: «Маховик управления — орган управления, имеющий форму колеса, со спицами или без спиц». «Штурвал — вид маховика управления, применяемого для изменения направления движения объекта». Вероятнее всего, эта штука действительно называется маховиком.

Answer (score 2):

[махови́к](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA) 
**2.** *техн.* **гладкое колесо**, предназначенное для вращения рукой.

*В отверстие мелькнуло искаженное гримасой рыжебородое лицо. Командир обеими руками вцепился в **маховик кремальеры.**

И это было последнее, что видел Шубин на борту "Летучего Голландца".

Тяжелый люк с лязгом захлопнулся. **Повернулся маховик**, намертво задраивая его изнутри. Всё!*
[Л. Д. Платов. Секретный фарватер](http://militera.lib.ru/prose/russian/platov1/16.html)

*Дверь открывалась с каким-то отвратительным скрипом, она была вся перекошена, её надо было как-то особо поддержать, потом крутануть **колесо кремальеры**, и только после этого она начинала открываться.*
[А. Макаров. Нельсон. Морские рассказы](https://books.google.ee/books?id=cQNDDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT153&lpg=PT153&dq=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B&source=bl&ots=BFNlLvJc4M&sig=ACfU3U2bxtgcoL-rOAaT5qHrsJdsNuQ4HA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwju4v-Nt_TfAhWMWywKHSAuDWkQ6AEwCXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B&f=false)

[Реечная передача (кремальера) применяется в тех случаях, когда нужно преобразовать вращательное движение в поступательное и обратно. Состоит из обычной прямозубой шестерни и зубчатой планки (рейки).]

Answer (score 1):

Только предположение: винтовой запор-барашек? кремальерный затвор?

Я нашла картинку, имитирующую "круглую деталь, вращением которой запирают дверь", только это прикол такой на обычной двери, сказано: **как** на подлодке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> КРЕМАЛЬЕРА
>
> замок (затвор), устанавливаемый на крышках люков и переборочных дверей
>   подводных лодок для быстрого их задраивания.

Читаем  и с "терминологией" -

[Межотсечная водонепроницаемая дверь подводной лодки](http://www.findpatent.ru/patent/218/2188139.html), но это, кажется, частный случай.

Нашла картинку "настоящую", но как называется закрывалка, не говорят...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за энтузиазм, жаль, что однозначного ответа Вам найти не удалось.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что этот элемент называется "задрайка". Он существует в разных вариациях исполнения. Круглая, по-видимому, относится к "винтовым задрайкам".